# Rails add value to params with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, parameters

In my application I created a Job, and on the Job show page I am trying to add the link for creating a Company to be added to that Job:

```
Company belongs_to Job
```

In my Job show.html.erb file I have:

```
<%= link_to "Add Company", new_company_path(:job_id=>@job.id) %>
```

But, in my Companies controller under new, I have:

```
@job = params[:job_id]
```

which returns nill. A check of the `params` hash shows that my `:job_id=>@job.id` value is not getting added.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there some thing with the strong parameters in Rails that I need to edit in order to allow my value to go from the Job show page to the Company controller?

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[ask]" and the linked pages. They'll help you write questions that fit SO's requirements. Also, please take the time to capitalize correctly ("rails" --> "Rails", "i" --> "I"). SO isn't a discussion board, it's an online reference book, like an encyclopedia or cookbook of programming problems and answers, so grammar and spelling is important.

Comment: What does `params.require :job_id` yield? If it returns your job id, then this confirms that indeed strong parameters are the culprit.

Comment: For some reason, when i changed it to be new_company_path(job_id: @job.id) this worked and my value made it into the params hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

on view

```
<%= link_to "Add Company", new_company_path(job_id: @job.id) %>
```

on controller

```
@job = params[:job_id]
```

Comment: Yes, i got it to work that way by fiddling with it. Im not sure why this way works and the other way did not.
Unless it has something to do with which version of rails you are running